# Two distinct forms doing just one POST through PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I've made two pages, each one with a `form` sending a selected image to localhost through a ajax script pointing to a save.php (containing the code to rename, realocate, and update MySQL with the destination folder/filename.

The first form works fine. But when the second page loads and the file is selected, nothing more happens. Like I was unable to use the `$_FILES` variable twice.

Here the html of the first page (The second one is the same, but I changed the `f_chassi` to `f_nmotor`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").on('click', function(){

var data = new FormData();
data.append('f_chassi', $('#f_chassi')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
url: 'salvar.php',
data: data,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
});
});
});


function filePreview(input) {

if (input.files) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#fotoPreview + img').remove();
$('#fotoPreview').before('<center><img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="75%"/></center>');
}
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
$("#f_chassi").change(function () {
filePreview(this);
});
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="titulo">O.S. <?php echo $_SESSION['novaOS']; ?></div>
<div id="novaos">

<div class="subtitulo">
<?php
echo "Placa: <i>".$_SESSION['placa']."</i>";
?>
</div>

<div class="subtitulo">FOTO CHASSI</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fotoPreview" action="fotoNumMotor.php">
<input type="file" name="f_chassi" id="f_chassi" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

<button type="button" id="btn">SALVAR</button>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="PRÓXIMA">
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the `save.php` code:

```
<?php   
if (!empty($_FILES['f_chassi'])){
    $dir_img = "../uploads/fotos/";
    $prefix  = time()."_";
    $fn  = $prefix."chassi_".$_FILES['f_chassi']['name'];
    $src = $dir_img.$fn;
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['f_chassi']['tmp_name'], $src);
    $chassi = $src;
    mysql_query ("UPDATE imagens SET chassi='$chassi' WHERE                 idp='".$_SESSION['novaOS']."'");
}

if (!empty($_FILES['f_nmotor'])){
    $dir_img = "../uploads/fotos/";
    $prefix  = time()."_";
    $fn  = $prefix."nmotor_".$_FILES['f_nmotor']['name'];
    $src = $dir_img.$fn;
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['f_nmotor']['tmp_name'], $src);
    $nmotor = $src;
    mysql_query ("UPDATE imagens SET nmotor='$nmotor' WHERE idp='".$_SESSION['novaOS']."'");
}?>
```

Comment: Do you have two versions of the javascript as well? You currently have `f_chassi` hardcoded in the JS: `data.append('f_chassi', $('#f_chassi')[0].files[0]);`

Comment: @JeremyHarris Yes I do have a javascript for each variable.
About the second question, sorry, but I didn't get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('form').submit(function(){

var dados = new FormData();
dados.append('fotoNumMotor', $('#f_nmotor').prop('files')[0]);

$.ajax({
url: 'salvar.php',
data: dados,
type: 'POST',

processData: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false
});
});
});
</script>
```

Also, thanks to @JeremyHarris for calling my attention to the `.append` variables.